# How do I get JSON response from a route?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, get

I have the following route:

```
@api_blueprint.route("/cars", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required()
def get_inventory():
    with session_scope():
        cars = dbu.list_cars()
        return jsonify(CarDetails(many=True).dump(cars))
```

I have to get the JSON response in a GET method which is a list of cars and insert into my html page.
I'm also not sure whether the code after the comment is true, it was one of my attempts to do something.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let method = "GET";
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cars";
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            /*get here JSON response from a route somehow*/
            document.getElementsByClassName("car_name").innerHTML = info.info[1]
            document.getElementsByClassName("car_price").innerHTML = info.info[2]
        }
        else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200){
            alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The response is following:

```
[
    {
        "carId": 1,
        "name": "Chevrolet",
        "price": 3547.14
    },
    {
        "carId": 2,
        "name": "Lotus",
        "price": 4558.47
    },
    {
        "carId": 3,
        "name": "Chevrolet",
        "price": 4385.96
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't see where the info variable comes from. For the js part, nowadays I suggest you use the fetch API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

When using `XMLHttpRequest` the response body can be found in the `responseText` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` instance. You've misplaced the position of where you read the response.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let method = "GET";
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cars";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(data);

      // getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements.
      // querySelector returns a single element based on a CSS selector.
      document.querySelector(".car_name").innerHTML = data.info[1]
      document.querySelector(".car_price").innerHTML = data.info[2]
    } else {
      // statusText shows the status message of the request.
      alert(xhr.statusText);
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Sidenote. Nowadays we have the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is the modern equivalent of the `XMLHttpRequest` interface. Though it is useful to know how `XMLHttpRequest` works, I'd recommend learning `fetch` as well.

The example below is the `fetch` equivalent of the code above.

```
let method = "GET";
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cars";

fetch(url, {
  method,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetching JSON went wrong - ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);

  document.querySelector(".car_name").innerHTML = data.info[1]
  document.querySelector(".car_price").innerHTML = data.info[2]
}).catch(error => {
  alert(error);
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me( It also seems that `console.log(data);` doesn't work too

Comment: Could you tell more about the request? Look in the network tab of the developer tools to find more details.